# Maven - purge local .m2 from all old artifacts versions

Tags: maven

I want to clean my local .m2 from all **old** versions of all artifacts. Leaving only the latest.
I'm aware of the [mvn dependency:purge-local-repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html) option, but it works only with a specific project in mind, and processes only the current project dependencies.
I'm thinking of writing a script to crawl all over the folder and process it, but it feels there might be a better solution...
I want to clean **ALL** of the .m2.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about simply deleting $HOME/.m2/repository folder ?

Comment: That is the "last resort" option. I'd like to save disk space and also time by not needing to download the artifacts again from my repository manager.

Comment: If you already use a repo manager it shouldn't take that long. Furthermore what do you understand by `old artifacts versions`?

Comment: `Old artifacts versions` means that if I have log4j 1.2.12, 1.2.13 and 1.2.14, after I run this, I'll have only 1.2.14 left in .m2.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you just want to reclaim disk space, you can remove all the SNAPSHOTs you have locally:

```
find ~/.m2/repository -name \*SNAPSHOT -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

If you're trying to bundle up a minimal functional local repository for use on another machine, then I would rename my ~/.m2/repository; do the builds I need then tar up the results.